# How do I add a zoom-in function to a CSS slideshow?

Tags: html, css, zooming

I am trying to add a slideshow to my website. I would like people to be able to click on and zoom in on the images (similar to this code, for example: https://codepen.io/JustinThyme/pen/NeERLX )

I have already created the automatic slideshow:

```css
.slideshow {
height: 350px;
margin: 0 auto;
position: relative;
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
display: flex;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
background-color: white;
}

.move {
height: 100%;
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
display: flex;
animation: moveSlideshow 50s linear infinite;
}

}
.move > img {
height: 150px;
width: auto;
}

.slideshow:hover .move {
animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes moveSlideshow {
0% {
transform: translateX(0%);
}
100% {
transform: translateX(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow">
<div class="move">
<img src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/53/45/31/360_F_53453175_hVgYVz0WmvOXPd9CNzaUcwcibiGao3CL.jpg " alt="" />
<img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/example-red-tag-example-red-square-price-tag-117502755.jpg " alt="" />
<img src="https://area515.org/wiki/images/a/a9/Example.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/true_reverend_insanity/images/7/70/Example.png/revision/latest?cb=20200328112134 " alt="" />
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg " alt="" />

<div class="move">
<img src="https://t4.ftcdn.net/jpg/00/53/45/31/360_F_53453175_hVgYVz0WmvOXPd9CNzaUcwcibiGao3CL.jpg " alt="" />
<img src="https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/example-red-tag-example-red-square-price-tag-117502755.jpg " alt="" />
<img src="https://area515.org/wiki/images/a/a9/Example.jpg" alt="" />
<img src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/true_reverend_insanity/images/7/70/Example.png/revision/latest?cb=20200328112134 " alt="" />
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/84/Example.svg " alt="" />

</div>
</div>
```

Is there any way I can edit the code to get it to have a function where if you click one of the images, it zooms in on that specific one and lets you view it in full?

I am not very experienced in coding at all. This is completely amalgamated together through trial and error until I got it to work. Feel free to edit it as you please, and if you need to use Javascript that should be alright, but would prefer just to stick to CSS and HTML if possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You Should Use JavaScript For Zooming Like Modal,

use this codes

**styles:**

```
body {
  font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 0 8px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  padding-top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: black;
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1200px;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #999;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.mySlides {
  display: none;
}

.cursor {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev,
.next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -50px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
  user-select: none;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover,
.next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

img {
  margin-bottom: -4px;
}

.caption-container {
  text-align: center;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2px 16px;
  color: white;
}

.demo {
  opacity: 0.6;
}

.active,
.demo:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

img.hover-shadow {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.hover-shadow:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}
```

**HTML codes:**

```
<h2 style="text-align:center">Slider</h2>

<div class="row">
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://ngninja.com/assets/posts/reactjs-102f9693a4201e678d5b02185717f4e2127d082c2f8afc0ed378cfc6cd814741.png" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(1)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://usefulangle.com/img/thumb/javascript.png" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(2)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://usefulangle.com/img/thumb/html.png" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(3)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <img src="https://dkl2gez3gijkp.cloudfront.net/lib/uploads/2012/12/css-3-help1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="openModal();currentSlide(4)" class="hover-shadow cursor">
  </div>
</div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal">
  <span class="close cursor" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">1 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://ngninja.com/assets/posts/reactjs-102f9693a4201e678d5b02185717f4e2127d082c2f8afc0ed378cfc6cd814741.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">2 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://usefulangle.com/img/thumb/javascript.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>

    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">3 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://usefulangle.com/img/thumb/html.png" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <div class="mySlides">
      <div class="numbertext">4 / 4</div>
      <img src="https://dkl2gez3gijkp.cloudfront.net/lib/uploads/2012/12/css-3-help1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    </div>
    
    <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
    <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

    <div class="caption-container">
      <p id="caption"></p>
    </div>


    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://ngninja.com/assets/posts/reactjs-102f9693a4201e678d5b02185717f4e2127d082c2f8afc0ed378cfc6cd814741.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(1)" alt="1">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://usefulangle.com/img/thumb/javascript.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(2)" alt="2">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://usefulangle.com/img/thumb/html.png" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(3)" alt="3">
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <img class="demo cursor" src="https://dkl2gez3gijkp.cloudfront.net/lib/uploads/2012/12/css-3-help1.jpg" style="width:100%" onclick="currentSlide(4)" alt="4">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
function openModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";
}

function closeModal() {
  document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
}

var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  var captionText = document.getElementById("caption");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
  captionText.innerHTML = dots[slideIndex-1].alt;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the help, but this doesn't really do anything like what my original slideshow did, unfortunately.